# Expanding vector calc expression...

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Trying to expand the following with the definition that $w \equiv \nabla \times \vec{U}$:
$$\nabla \times (\vec{U} \cdot \nabla)\vec{U}$$

I know the cross product transfers over somehow, but I'm not sure how.

I believe this is wrong...
$$(\vec{U} \cdot \nabla) (\nabla \times \vec{U})$$

Could anyone suggest an identity to use to expand the first expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $\vec{A} = \vec{B} = \vec{U}$ in the vector identity $$\nabla(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}) = (\vec{A}\cdot \nabla)\vec{B} + (\vec{B}\cdot \nabla)\vec{A} + \vec{A}\times(\nabla\times \vec{B}) + \vec{B}\times(\nabla\times \vec{A})$$ to obtain $\nabla U^2 = 2(\vec{U}\cdot \nabla)\vec{U} + 2\vec{U}\times \vec{\omega}$ or $$(\vec{U}\cdot \nabla)\vec{U} = \nabla\left(\frac{1}{2}U^2\right) - \vec{U}\times \vec{\omega}$$ Since the curl of a gradient is zero, $$\nabla\times (\vec{U}\cdot \nabla)\vec{U} = -\nabla\times (\vec{U}\times \omega) = \nabla\times(\vec{\omega}\times \vec{U})$$ By the vector identity $$\nabla \times (\vec{A}\times \vec{B}) = (\vec{B}\cdot \nabla)\vec{A} - (\vec{A}\cdot \nabla)\vec{B} + (\nabla \cdot \vec{B})\vec{A} - (\nabla \cdot \vec{A})\vec{B}$$ applied to $\vec{A} =\vec{\omega}$ and $\vec{B} = \vec{U}$, we derive $$\nabla \times (\vec{U}\cdot \nabla)\vec{U} = (\vec{U}\cdot \nabla)\vec{\omega} - (\vec{\omega}\cdot \nabla)\vec{U} + (\nabla \cdot \vec{U})\vec{\omega} - (\nabla \cdot \vec{\omega})\vec{U}$$ Note that $\nabla\cdot \vec{\omega}$, being the divergence of a curl, is zero. Hence $$\nabla\times(\vec{U}\cdot \nabla)\vec{U} = (\vec{U}\cdot \nabla)\vec{\omega} - (\vec{\omega}\cdot \nabla)\vec{U} + (\nabla\cdot \vec{U})\vec{\omega}$$